# Prevent FlexibleSpaceBar to hide when collapsed and when floating is true

Tags: flutter, expandablelistview, appbar, flutter-sliver

In order to expend my Flexible Space Bar when user scrolls up, I set floating to true on the corresponding SliverAppBar.
But then when the Flexible Space Bar is collapsed its opacity is animated from 1 to 0:

[image]

my code is the following

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                expandedHeight: 200.0,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  title: Text('test'),
                ),
              ),
              SliverFixedExtentList(
                itemExtent: 150.0,
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  [
                    Container(color: Colors.red),
                    Container(color: Colors.purple),
                    Container(color: Colors.green),
                    Container(color: Colors.orange),
                    Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                    Container(color: Colors.pink),
                    Container(color: Colors.red),
                    Container(color: Colors.purple),
                    Container(color: Colors.green),
                    Container(color: Colors.orange),
                    Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                    Container(color: Colors.pink),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I still want the floating effect, how can I prevent my Flexible Space Bar to hide when it's collapsed?

Comment: What Exactly are you looking to do here .?

Comment: @anmol.majhail I have a tabbar inside a flexible space, i'd like those tabs to expand  as soon as the user scrolls up, it works if i set floating to true on the corresponding sliver app bar, but the same setting (floatting = true) turns the flexible opacity to 0 when user scrolls down, which I'd like to avoid, so in my very example i'd like "test" not to fade out when user scrolls down

Comment: use `bottom:` instead of `flexible space`. added it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the code you've shared but the Text inside `SliverAppBar` doesn't change its opacity. I'm currently running Flutter version 2.2.1.

[image]

I also checked if there might be old bugs related to this issue, but I haven't found anything. I suggest try running the same code again with the latest version of Flutter to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [SliverPersistentHeader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html) instead of SliverAppBar.

[Additional video.](https://youtu.be/E3-WdYBrEDc?t=169)